# Azure Logic App Custom Connector - SOAP to REST - Pass HTTP header from REST to SOAP request

Tags: rest, azure, web-services, soap, http-headers

In Azure I am able to create a Logic App Custom Connector to a SOAP API endpoint using Call Mode: SOAP to REST. 
This SOAP Web Service needs an HTTP Header named Cookie with the value LoginCert=. 
When modifying the Request of this connector I cannot find a way to add the Cookie HTTP header in the REST request and have that same Cookie be added to the SOAP request. Does anyone know how or if it is even possible to have HTTP headers from the REST request forwarded to the SOAP request made by the custom connector?

PS: This is possible in Azure via the API Management tool's REST to SOAP using the same WSDL, and then using the newly created REST endpoints inside of a Logic App Flow but this is not the solution.

TLDR: How can one add a HTTP header in an SOAP to REST Azure Logic App Custom Connector so the header is forwarded to the SOAP endpoint?

Comment: Please check if this is something you are looking for- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/david_burgs_blog/2018/02/28/logic-app-soap-pass-through-custom-connector/ 
Also check this too http://twocents.nl/?p=1998
Hope it helps.

Comment: @MohitVerma-MSFT Thanks for the links. I hadn't tried SOAP pass through but I just did and have the same problem. In code view I add the header "Cookie":"LoginCert=<valueFromLoginService>" and that header is not getting passed through the the SOAP call to the external service.

Comment: Seems this is a pretty common request. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/20204245-add-support-for-passing-cookie-header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently supported by the SOAP to REST WSDL generated custom connectors for SOAP. You need indeed to either escape to APIM or you need to form the request payloads via LIQUID action then use the HTTP request action's advanced option to specify the cookie.